# Vanilla JS: Reveal only the next element at the same parent group

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, parent-child, ejs

I am trying to create few tabs - with loop. 
Then when you click on the tab's name which is a span, its expand(or hide) the next span, which is below it. The problem is that the function works only in the first created tab from the loop and if you click on the second/third, etc tab - the function triggers only at the first tab.

Was trying with querySelector and nextElementSibling without any success.

Using ejs template, express and vanilla javascript only.

This is the loop/tab.

```
<div>   
    <% listedProducts.forEach(function(product) { %>
        <div class="col">
            <span id="info" class="b-d"  onclick="hideReveal()">
                <%= product.name %>
            </span>
            <span>
                <img src="<%= product.logo %>" alt="">
                <p class="r-d"><%= product.supplierCompany %></p>
                <p class="r-d"><%= product.dateListed %></p>
                <p class="r-d"><%= product.dateApproved %></p>
                <p class="r-d"><%= product.supplierName %></p>
            </span>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

and the function

```
function hideReveal() {
    var tab = document.getElementById("info");
    if (tab.style.display === "none") {
        tab.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        tab.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Would like a little help, please. Thank you and have a nice weekend.

Comment: all your span items seem to have the same id, and only the 1st one is returned by your getElementById call. you should use a unique id for each span, and add an argument to your hideReveal method to find the appropriate span element in your DOM

Comment: You are using the same id for all span tag due to which whenever a span is clicked it gets the first element with that id, you need to use `class` instead of `id` when you are using it on multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

in your click handler, pass an event argument, e.g., `function clickHandler(evt)` then say `var thisTab = evt.target.id`. This assumes you have an id attribute on the tab(s). Then you can toggle the open/closed class of thisTab's [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild.)